# Dynamically set scroll coordinates & change DOM element with 200px scroll tolerance from these coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scroll

I've got a single page site with two `div` modules that expand when clicked.

The first is at the top, in the Hero section and with the current code works as desired. The second is much further down the page in another section. Currently this second module closes as soon as the scroll takes place.

What I need to do is get the documents scroll coordinates when the `div` is clicked. Then once the user scrolls 200px up or down the `div` closes back up. Regardless of where it *(the `div`)* is on the site.

All the questions I found here and elsewhere only refer to setting the scroll tolerance relative to the window position on page load. But for me that's no goon. This site is responsive, and as it changes the initial positions of the `div`'s will / can be unknown. I need someway of dynamically storing the viewports scroll position when the `div`'s are clicked and assigning the 200px tolerance then.

I hope that makes sense. I've been at this for like 12+hrs now. **SOS** *:)*

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paralellos/gbdxahox/1/#&togetherjs=r4fxSIwK3D)

If you don't want to go over to *Fiddle*, **Here's the requisite code**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <section id="hero">
    <div>
      <div class="module-cta hero-cta">
        <a class="module-cta__button"><!-- Fallback location -->
          <span class="module-cta__text">PRESS ME</span>
        </a>
        <div class="module-cta__open">
          <div class="module-cta__open-inner">
            <div class="hero-cta__contact-points">
              <div class="phone">
                <div class="hero-cta_contact_logo">
                  <span><!-- phone.svg" --></span>
                </div><!-- .service-logo -->
                <div class="contact_trigger">
                  <a>Scroll down to 200px to see</a>
                </div><!-- .contact_trigger -->
              </div><!-- .phone -->
              <div class="email">
                <div class="hero-cta_contact_logo">
                  <span><!-- email.svg --></span>
                </div><!-- .service-logo -->
                <div class="contact_trigger">
                  <a>this div fold back up</a>
                </div><!-- .contact_trigger -->
              </div><!-- .email -->
            </div><!-- .hero-cta__contact-points -->
            <button class="module-cta__close module-cta__cancel"><i class="icon"><span></span></i></button>
          </div><!-- .hero-cta__open-inner -->
        </div><!-- .hero-cta__open -->
      </div><!-- .hero-cta -->
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="spacer"></section>
  <section id="service_area">
    <div class="area_input">
      <div class="module-cta area-cta wow fadeInUp" id="form_module">
        <a class="module-cta__button area-cta__button">
          <span class="module-cta__text area-cta__text">NOW PRESS ME</span>
        </a>
        <div class="module-cta__open area-cta__open">
          <div class="module-cta__open-inner area-cta__open-inner">
            <div class="area-cta__search">
              <form class="postcode_form" id="postcode_form" name="postcode_form" action="#">
                <input type="number" id="your_postcode" class="your_postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="3???">
                <button type="button" class="area-btn"><span></span></button>
                <a class="call-now">##########</a>
              </form>
            </div><!-- .area-cta__search -->
            <button class="module-cta__close module-cta__cancel"><i class="icon"><span></span></i></button>
          </div><!-- .area-cta__open-inner -->
        </div><!-- .area-cta__open -->
      </div><!-- .area-cta -->
    </div><!-- .area_input -->
  </section>
  <section class="spacer"></section>
</body>
```

**Script:**
*I'm sure a lot of this can be cleaned up and shrunk, but for now I'm just trying to get it all going.*

```
// opens & closes modules by clicking module name
$('.module-cta__button').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).parent().hasClass('hero-cta')){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('module-cta--active');
  } else {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('area-cta')){
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('module-cta--active');
    }
  }
});

// closes modules with .module-cta__close btn
$('.module-cta__close').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).closest('div .module-cta').hasClass('module-cta--active')){
    $(this).closest('div .module-cta').removeClass('module-cta--active');
  }
});

// closes modules on scroll.
// * works but doesn't apply scroll tolerance of 200px for #area
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var currentPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var module = $('div .module-cta');
  if(module.hasClass('module-cta--active') && module.position().top <= currentPos+200){
    $('div .module-cta--active').removeClass('module-cta--active');
  }
});


// closes modules when escape key is pressed
$(window).keydown(function(escape){
  var key = escape.which;
  if(key == 27){
    $('div .module-cta--active').removeClass('module-cta--active');
  }
});
```

see *Fiddle* for `css`

- *Thanks for any help or useful suggestions in advanced.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a much smaller and simpler demonstration, just to show you what variables you need to accomplish this. Essentially, when a div is clicked, capture the current document scroll position using `$(document).scrollTop()`. Also store a refference to the current div that has been clicked.

When scrolling, check the difference between the current scroll and the new scroll, and using your clicked div reference, shrink the div when the difference is 200 or greater. JS fiddle below;

https://jsfiddle.net/jLqu4pas/

***Code from Fiddle;***

```
var currentScroll;
var lastClickedDiv;

$('section').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'height' : '400'})
  currentScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  lastClickedDiv = $(this);

  console.log(currentScroll);
})

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > currentScroll + 200){
    lastClickedDiv.css({'height' : 0})
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Lewis this has done the job. I new I needed to store the click and scroll data and the use it for comparison. I just couldn't work out how to do it. In my attempts I wasn't building the variables outside my click function like you have. That's obviously why the scroll function wasn't having any of it. lol.

Answer (score 0):

So I've put together a script that will potentially help you.

I've done some basic testing on it, but if you come across any problems make a comment.

```
// Generate offsets and return them as an object
function generateOffsets($element, tolerance)
{
  var offsets = $element.offset(),
      offsetTop = offsets.top;

  return {
    scrollPos: offsetTop,
    toleranceTop: offsetTop - tolerance,
    toleranceBottom: offsetTop + tolerance
  };
}

// Run a callback when the user leaves the scroll tolerance of a set of elements
function closeOnScroll($elements, tolerance, callback)
{
  $elements.each(function() {
    var $element = $(this),
        offsets = generateOffsets($element, tolerance),
        resizeEvent;

    // On resize, regenerate the offsets so they stay up to date
    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
      resizeEvent = e;
      offsets = generateOffsets($element, tolerance);
    });

    // On scroll check if we've left the tolerance area, if so run the event and unbind
    $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
      var windowPos = $(this).scrollTop();

      if (windowPos < offsets.toleranceTop || windowPos > offsets.toleranceBottom) {
        callback($element);
        $(this).unbind(e);
        $(this).unbind(resizeEvent);
      }
    }); 
  });
}

// Example: Apply the event to a set of elements
$('.btn').click(function() {
  closeOnScroll($('div .module-cta'), 200, function($element) {
    $element.removeClass('module-cta--active');
  });
});
```

The thing to remember with thie script is that it needs to be applied EVERY time the user clicks your button. You may say, *WHY WOULD YOU DO THAT* - but it actually has some serious performance implications.

The events rely on both scroll and resize, both of which are very slow, especially if not debounced like in this script. However, what I do in the script is unbind the events once it has occured. Otherwise, the resize and scroll would keep happening for each and every one of your buttons until the end of time. By 'unbinding' the event, you ensure long running performance of your page.

Wouldn't want to ruin those pretty animations would we?

Comment: Thanks for your input @AndrewKhan. For now I've implemented Lewis' method below. Though after inspecting the Chrome Dev Timeline I have seen my performance is lacking. *So many red marks.* Once I get the rest of the site built and implementation bugs sorted I'll have an attempt at your code. Like the `unbind` which I tried but then it only fired once.

Comment: You have to run the function every time you click, otherwise it will only fire once.